# VSCode adding a condition in launch.json to distinguish based on file type

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to have a condition in launch.json so that we always say debug and based on the file type or the file name, it could launch different programs?

Eg. If the file name is *.test.jsx we need to run jest else we need to run chrome.